# How to store dictionary in Redis Cache/Hash in c#

Tags: caching, c#-4.0, dictionary, redis

I am using cache to store `ENUMCACHE` like blow.

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["_ENUMCACHE"] == null)
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("_ENUMCACHE",new Dictionary(string,Enumeration>();
```

Now I need to change Redis Cahche/Hash.

How can I able to store dictionary in Redis.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum<string, string> dic = new Enum<string, string>();
dic.Add("test","test");

connection.Set<Enum<string, string>>("SOMETEST", dic, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));

dic = connection.Get<Enum<string, string>>("SOMETEST");
```

Comment: @El Captain v2.0 is it possible to do it with Dictionary<string,object> type? Im using CSRedis from Nuget.